# Derivation of fixed-point $\tt atan2$ with self-normalization

Tags: fixed-point, math

I'm trying to understand the maths behind this [Fast fixed-point $\tt atan2$ calculation with self-normalization](http://dspguru.com/dsp/tricks/fixed-point-atan2-with-self-normalization). In particular, equation $(2)$ for `theta1` appears to provide a first-degree expansion of some series. Similarly, equation $(2a)$ under "QUICK NOTE" seems to expand this series.

- What is the series that's being expanded?
- How *exactly* is equation $(2)$ derived?

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact question, nearly a decade later - and think I figured out the cool fixed-points tricks thanks to and [edaboard thread](https://www.edaboard.com/threads/question-about-polynomial-atan-and-fixed-point-atan2-with-self-normalization.340726/) and helpful write up in the [IEEE Signal Processing Magazine](https://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Emignotte/IFT2425/Documents/EfficientApproximationArctgFunction.pdf).

First, some trig identities are used to transform the problem into one that is self-regularizing:

$$ \begin{align}
\tan(\pi/4 - \theta) &= \frac{\tan(\pi/4)+\tan(-\theta)}{1-\tan(\pi/4)\tan(-\theta)}\\
 &= \frac{1-\tan(\theta)}{1+\tan(\theta)}
\end{align}
$$

Here $\tan(\theta) = y/x$, therefore

$$ \begin{align}
\tan(\pi/4 - \theta) &= \frac{1-y/x}{1+y/x} = \frac{x-y}{x+y}\\
\pi/4 - \theta &= \arctan \left( \frac{x-y}{x+y} \right) \\
\theta &= \pi/4 - \arctan \left( r \right) \\
\end{align} 
$$

where $r = \frac{x-y}{x+y}$. That's a great self-normalizing trick with zero approximations so far. Since we want $\theta$, we can solve something that is a function of $r$, which is already guaranteed to be $-1 < r < 1$ (in the first quadrant). Now we just need an easy expression for $\arctan(r)$ between $-1 < r < 1$. There's a bunch of techniques to do that, but the simplest is to just fit a line that goes through $r=\{-1,0,1\}$, the corresponding $\arctan(r)$ is $\{-\pi/4,0,\pi/4\}$. So a quick a dirty approximation gives us:

$$ \arctan(r) \approx \frac{\pi}{4}r$$

put it all together (for the first quadrant):

$$\theta \approx \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{4}r$$

To get more accurate, you can get better polynomials to approximate $\arctan(r)$. Things like the [Remez algorithm](https://www.odelama.com/data-analysis/Approximation-to-Elementary-Transcendental-Functions/) can help find those, and the [IEEE Signal Processing Magazine](https://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Emignotte/IFT2425/Documents/EfficientApproximationArctgFunction.pdf) also gives a method and compares polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

it's an approximation.

a better approximation is in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20444/books-resources-for-implementing-various-mathematical-functions-in-fixed-point-a/20482#20482):

$$ \arctan(u) \approx \frac{u}{f(u^2)}  \quad \quad -1 \le u \le 1  $$

where

$$ \begin{align}
f(u^2)& = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{4} \ a_n \ u^{2n} \\
a_0  &  =  1.0 \\
a_1  &  =  0.33288950512027 \\
a_2  &  =  -0.08467922817644 \\
a_3  &  =  0.03252232640125 \\
a_4  &  =  -0.00749305860992 \\
\end{align} $$

not as fast, but quite accurate.  not bit-perfect accurate, but very accurate.

for `atan2()`, you need to put it in the correct tilted quadrant:

$$ \operatorname{atan2}(y,x) = \arg\{ x + j\,y \} =
\begin{cases}
\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) &\text{if } 0 < |y| \le x, \\
\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) &\text{if } 0 < |x| \le y, \\
-\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) &\text{if } y \le -|x| < 0, \\
\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \pm \pi &\text{if } x \le -|y| < 0, \\
\text{undefined} &\text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y = 0.
\end{cases} $$

this will require two fixed-point divisions, but you can arrange it so that the result is always no greater than 1 in magnitude (the numerator is always smaller in magnitude than the denominator).